# google maps Iframe and Foundation 3 Reveal centering issue

Tags: google-maps, zurb-foundation, reveal.js

I have been looking for a concrete answer to the issue I'm having for more than 4 hours. I couldn't find any that fits mine.

My situation is quite simple, I'm embedding a google maps iframe within a reveal modal window, but when it's loaded and shown the map shows off center, the pin is way to the left side.

Have in mind that I'm **not** working with maps API in this case, I'm just using an iframe.

Comment: Could you post you code? And maybe an example on jsfiddle?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So after continue reading trying to find for a solution. I found that Reveal js plugin gave visibility:hidden; to modal box but also was giving it a display:none; attribute.

Removing the display attribute from both none and block statements, leaving only visibility and adding an attribute to my stylesheet display:block !important; to the modal solved the issue.

I have been reading that maps have issues on hidden divs. the resize() code for it didn't work for me (maybe because I was using an iframe) so I found the solution on these little css changes.

Comment: I don't understand where do you remove the display attribute.